# Given an element $y$ name inEnglish of $x$ such that $f(x)=y$

Tags: functions, terminology

My question is about English wording.

For an application $f$ and an element $y$ in the *image* of $f$, what is the name of an element $x$ such that $f(x)=y$? In French we say that $x$ is *un antécédent* of $y$. While *antecedent* is an English word, can it be used for that purpose? Thanks.

Comment: The word antecedent is not used this way in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ is in the domain of the function f.

Edit: Just realised I'm not really answering your question. I've never had to refer to the relationship between x and y. In my classes, x is either referred to as the input or the argument of the function. However, I do believe that you can say that "$x$ is the **pre-image** of $y$".

Comment: I just realised. made an edit. thanks.

Comment: If you say that $x$ is the pre-image of $y$, is this not meaning that $x$ is the ONLY element such that $f(x)=y$?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre: Yes. Unless you know that $f$ is injective, you should say that $x$ is *a* pre-image of $y$, or that $x$ is in the *fibre* of $y$. By the way, in English *application* cannot be used for *function*; the choices are *function* and *map(ping)*.